# Last email exchanged in Outlook

Tags: parsing, microsoft-outlook

I use outlook for all communications with my friends; I want to find out when I last exchanged email from a friend. Normally the emails that I get from my friends are moved to folders in outlook.

Is there a program that automatically parses through all my outlook folders and creates a view that shows me when I last exchanged email with my friends? I'm expecting the end result to be something like this:

```
FROM    | SUBJECT         | RECEIVED
Friend1 | Great meeting you at Party | Feb-1-2011
Friend2 | Completed homework? | Feb-1-2002
Friend3 | Forward my resume please | Dec-1-2010
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a program that does this exactly, but you could do this with fairly minimal effort using Powershell.

Have a look at [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jmanning/using-powershell-for-outlook-automation)

Basically you'd get the folder object, then run some selects over the contents.